# How to append sort by a field in phalcon relationship?

Tags: php, relationship, phalcon, phalcon-orm

I have a situation where I want to sort my video blogs by `recent upload` and `views` i.e either sort by recent or sort by views. I tried the below code but now I have no idea what to do next?

```
$category = VideoBlogCategoryModel::getVideoBlogCategoryBySlug($categorySlug);
$category->getVideoBlogs(); // This is the relationship
```

**Initialize function:**

```
// Configure relation with VideoBlogModel
$this->hasMany('id', VideoBlogModel::class, 'category_id', array(
    'alias' => 'videoBlogs',
    'foreignKey' => true,
    'cxAction' => static::ACTION_CASCADE_DELETE,
    'params' => array(
        'order' => 'created_at DESC'
    )
));
```

How can I do something like `$category->getVideoBlogs('order','views DESC')` or `$category->getVideoBlogs('order','created_at DESC')` ?

From the initialize function you can see I already have an order param which is fetching the video blogs in descending order however I want it dynamic so that I can pass something like **order by views** as I mentioned above.

**My Ajax:**

```
// Sort By Recent and Views Feature
$('.cx_sort_video').change(function(e){
    // loading bar
    parameters.sort = $(this).val();
    ajaxLoadVideo(parameters);
});
```

**Sort by dropdown:**

```
<li class="list-inline-item">
    <span>SORT BY: </span>
    <select style="border:0px;" class="cx_sort_video">
        <option> RECENT</option>
        <option> VIEWS</option>
    </select>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `getRelated(<relationshipName/Alias>, <array>parameters)`

```php
$category->getRelated('videoBlogs', [
    'order' => 'created_at DESC'
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how to pass it from here `$category->getVideoBlogs(?);` 

Actually I have to change the order by `recent videos` i.e created_at desc and order by views i.e `views desc`

Comment: I was confused first when I saw your answer but later I understood :) 
In getter I added a param called $order like `public function getVideoBlogs($order){
        return $this->getRelated('videoBlogs', $order);
    }`

And then from controller I passed the order like `$category->getVideoBlogs($order);`

Comment: Yeah you can definitely do that! Personally I'd avoid creating a wrapper around getRelated as it is publicly accessible. So in your controller you could use the example I provided as well :)